# Azure SQL Grant Access for AD User in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms

I set an azure ad admin (global admin) for our azure sql server, now i tried to grant a ad user access to the sql database.
I followed the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEPyPsGEevw, because i didn't found a better explenation.
As described in the video, i created a query in the target database context:

`CREATE USER [user@domain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`

that raises this exception:

> Msg 33134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Principal 'user@domain.com' could not be resolved. Error message: 'AADSTS7000219: 'client_assertion' or > 'client_secret' is required for the 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant type.
>   Trace ID: 95da6617-732c-42bf-b74b-40a4fdffe000
>   Correlation ID: cf4b894f-f945-492c-a77f-e2976ac72eab
>   Timestamp: 2020-06-09 17:58:48Z

When i try the same in master db, it works.

What goes wrong? Or could you provide me a source of a step by step guide? I didn't found a real good description...

Comment: Which region are you creating the database in? Seems to be a reproducible issue at the moment, I'm getting the same error in Australia East.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue in West Europe on one database, while creating users from external provider is successful on other databases on the same Azure SQL instance. I've filed a support case with Azure support.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in UK South

Comment: Scaling up to S1 seemed to resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experiencing exactly the same issue in the UK South region.

This isn't a fix, but it seems to resolve the issue for me (i.e. it's a work around). To fix:

- scale the database to at least S3,
- apply the changes
- then scale it back to the level that you require.

The changes should be applied.

Our database was at S0 when we tried to create the AAD users/groups initially and we received exactly the same error as pointed out above.