# azure user-assigned identity for azure sql fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use a user assigned identity (from a Azure container instance) to connect to an Azure sql database.

following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql

it works for System assigned identities, but not for user assigned ones. when trying to create the contained user, using the user assigned identity i get this error

```
Msg 33134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Principal 'user-assigned-identity-name' could not be resolved. Error message: 'AADSTS7000219: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret' is required for the 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant type
```

Am i missing something here or have i misunderstood user assigned identities? Can they be used to login in to and query sql server?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289205/azure-sql-grant-access-for-ad-user-in-ssms

Answer (score 0):

The guide you followed is used for **system-assigned** managed identity, because it enables you to authenticate to services that support Azure AD authentication, *without needing to insert credentials into your code*. But credential is necessary for **user-assigned** managed identity.

You could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-ua-arm), and use the [way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-ua-arm#get-an-access-token) to get `access_token`.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&client_id=af825a31-b0e0-471f-baea-96de555632f9&resource=https://management.azure.com/' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$ArmToken = $content.access_token
```